# does eclipse have it's own JDK? or it uses the JDK on my computer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java programming and I haven't used any java IDE,
I intalled Java JDK 8 on my computer and been doing some coding through Notepad++ and compiling it via cmd commands.

Since now that i'm comfortable coding manually, I wanna try to use IDE and decided to get the latest "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". what I got is actually a .zip file no installation or something which is odd.

My question is does the eclipse uses the JDK I installed on my computer or it has it's own? if so how would I know which version of java does my eclipse run?

and if does use the JDK on my computer, if I want to update the JDK intalled on my computer do I have to uninstall the old one or I can just overwrite it with the new JDK build??

Thanks,
CC

Comment: By default, eclipse uses it's [own compiler](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/). It is possible to use another build tool (like maven with m2e, which is included) in which case it uses whatever that is set to.

Comment: As a follow-up: The JDK that you use to develop and run Java projects in Eclipse can be different from the JDK (JRE?) Eclipse itself runs on. There is a setting for this in projects (and it's probably more important to you than whatever Eclipse uses).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - the JDT isn't a compiler. Eclipse requires you to have Java installed, and I believe it uses your system installed `javac`, as well as Maven. Have I been misunderstanding that?

Comment: @cricket_007 [JDT Core](https://eclipse.org/jdt/core/) (from the link) **is** *an incremental Java compiler. Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it is based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler. In particular, it allows to run and debug code which still contains unresolved errors.*

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse uses externally installed JDKs to run itself (it's written in Java, after all) and to provide the core libraries for the code you write (such as the `java.*` packages). By default, Eclipse will use its own compiler, ECJ, that has deep integrations with the IDE to provide features such as detailed error reporting and sometimes even partial compilation of invalid classes.

It's possible to override the compiler via some plugin (for example, you can explicitly specify a compiler in a POM via m2eclipse, though the default there still uses ECJ), but that's uncommon if you're still compiling Java code.

Eclipse has support for using multiple JDKs, for example for different versions (maybe you have backwards compatibility with 1.6) or different vendors. Depending on how your OS is set up, if your main `JAVA_HOME` is set through a symlink, you may not need to update Eclipse at all if you perform a minor upgrade. In the case of a major upgrade, though, you will probably need to go to "Installed JREs" and add or modify an entry.

Answer (score -1):

1.the jdk you installed in your computor is global situation. it can effect  anywhere if you have configured the environment variables.

2.configured the environment variables,run cmd like this,the java version will be show,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml58b.png)

3.generally, one JDK , one computor is enough.if  you want to update jdk, just download new jdk and override the old jdk .